# Google Places Autocomplete, Clear if nothing selected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API, I have a form that uses the Autocomplete function. I would like it so that if the user types text in and does not select it from the dropdown, the input should clear the input and display an alert i.e. "Please select a valid address"

I am not sure how this would be done, I assume using a `onblur` event and a JSON call to verify if the address entered is valid? I just can't seem to fins where this code would be added.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/725xd1r6/